# How to open only one popup window and restrict it to only one using JavaScript only (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

I want to open **only one window** on clicking the button. Even if I click the button multiple times, I want only one window (refreshed window).

Here is my code:

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    const width = 800;
    const height = 500;
    const left = window.screen.width/2 - width/2;
    const top = window.screen.height/2 - height/2;
    const windowFeatures = `width=${width},height=${height},status,resizable,left=${left},top=${top},screenX=${left},screenY=${top}`;

    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","",windowFeatures);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me update my code for above problem using **Javascript ONLY**

Answer (score 0):

Store the new window object in a variable, and check the value on click of button. If defined just hard reload that window else open new window. Refreshing the new window will only work when domain name is same else it will throw error DOMException because of cross-origin frame.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
        let newWindow;
        function myFunction() {
            if (newWindow) {
                newWindow.location.reload(true);
            } else {
                const width = 800;
                const height = 500;
                const left = window.screen.width / 2 - width / 2;
                const top = window.screen.height / 2 - height / 2;
                const windowFeatures = `width=${width},height=${height},status,resizable,left=${left},top=${top},screenX=${left},screenY=${top}`;

                newWindow = window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", "", windowFeatures);
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by refreshed window... do you want to refresh the new window which you opened?

Comment: I mean, If I click the button second time then the same window should open, but with refreshed content (even though the content is same).

Comment: Why do you want to open the same window, when it is already open. It should be refreshed once you click again on button.

Comment: my url is dynamic in actual case, and it is not getting refreshed if I click on the button more than once.

Comment: ohh url is dynamic so, on click of button close the existing window and open a new window. You will have only one window opened.